Is this formula expressing $\operatorname{erf} \left(\tfrac 1 {\sqrt 2}\right)$ as an infinite series already known?
Is the following formula already known?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k k!}{(2k + 1)!} = \sqrt{\frac{e\pi}{2}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
The right-hand side is known since Ramanujan, but the left-hand side has not been reported in the literature.
So I wonder if this connection between these two expressions is already known.

"The right member is known since Ramanujan but the left member has not been reported in the literature." -- What do you mean by this? In particular, what do you mean by "The right member is known since Ramanujan"? How can a "member" be known or unknown?

@MartinNicholson : Do you know if the more general identity (10) is known?

@MartinNicholson : Thank you for the references. In some cases, it seems much easier to prove a thing than to find it in the literature.

This was answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063482 and its related linked questions.

Removing $+1$ from the denominator adds $1$ to the sum as in $\sum\limits _{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k k!}{(2k )!} = \sqrt{\frac{e\pi}{2}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1$, apparently related to $\sum\limits _{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k , \Gamma(k +\frac32)} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

@CrawCraw : Do you have a response to the answers below?

It looks like the only actual answer to this question with a pointer to the literature for this identity was in a now-deleted comment of Martin Nicholson.

Let
$$f(x):=\sqrt{\pi } e^{x^2/4} \operatorname{erf}(x/2).$$
Then
$$f'(x)=\tfrac12\, x f(x)+1.$$
So, by the Leibniz formula, for $m\ge1$,
$$f^{(m+1)}(x)=\tfrac12\,x f^{(m)}(x)+\tfrac m2\,f^{(m-1)}(x)$$
and hence
$$f^{(m+1)}(0)=\tfrac m2\,f^{(m-1)}(0).$$
Also, $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$. So, for all $k\ge0$ we have $f^{(2k)}(0)=0$ and $f^{(2k+1)}(0)=k!$.
So,
$$\sqrt{\pi } e^{x^2/4} \operatorname{erf}(x/2)=f(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!}{(2k+1)!}\,x^{2k+1}. \tag{10}\label{10}$$
Your identity is a special case of \eqref{10} with $x=\sqrt2$.

Is it clear that $f(x)$ must equal its Taylor series?

@SamHopkins : Yes, because $f$ is an entire function.

Why the downvote? Is anything wrong with this answer?

If you write \text{erf} instead of \operatorname{erf} then people following your example may type something like $2\text{erf}(x)$ instead of $2\operatorname{erf}(x),$ which looks conspicuously different. Clearly the latter is standard.

This answer is off topic.

@MartinNicholson : Thank you for your response. The post seems to actually contain two questions: the one in the title and the other one being "So I wonder if this connection between these two members already exists." This answer shows that "this connection [...] exists."

@JannikPitt : The post seems to actually contain two questions: the one in the title and the other one being "So I wonder if this connection between these two members already exists." This answer shows that "this connection [...] exists."

@MartinNicholson : I think, whatever you think MO's evolution has been, your responses here still matter, at least to other users.

WolframAlpha returns this result promptly, so it is probably known or straightforward to show. See here.

This can be a comment
